# How to create a set in Ballerina?

Tags: set, ballerina

I have a requirement to create a `set` of strings using an `array` of strings in Ballerina. Other than using `reduce()` or checking `indexOf()` before inserting, I couldn't find a way to create a `set` using Ballerina programming language.

```
    string[] arr = ["a", "b", "c", "a", "d", "c"];
    string[] set = arr.reduce(function(string[] accum, string item) returns string[] {
            if accum.indexOf(item) == () {
                accum.push(item);
            }
            return accum;
        }, []);
```

Is there a better way to create a set in Ballerina?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since what you want is just set of strings, I would suggest to use a map.

```
import ballerina/io;

public function main() {
    string[] s = ["a", "b", "a"];
    map<()> m = {};
    foreach var i in s {
        m[i] = ();
    }
    string[] unique = m.keys();
    io:println(unique);
}
```

For set of complex type, we can go with a `table` and do something similar to what we did with map.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This should work. However, don't you think it would be better if there was a `set` data structure out of the box?

Answer (score 5):

This is not exactly a set but recently Ballerina [query expression](https://ballerina.io/learn/data/#query-expressions) has got a `group by` clause that can be used to filter out duplicates from data containers and thus effectively creating "set"-version of the container.

```
$ bal version
Ballerina 2201.8.3 (Swan Lake Update 8)
Language specification 2023R1
Update Tool 1.4.2
```

```
$ cat uniq.bal
import ballerina/io;
function uniq(anydata[] data) returns anydata[] {
    return 
        from var item in data 
        group by item 
        select item;
}
type Data record {|
    int x;
    int y;
|};
public function main() {
    int[] nums = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5];
    io:println(uniq(nums));
    string[] strs = ["foo","foo","bar","bar","zoo","zoo"];
    io:println(uniq(strs));
    Data[] data = [{x:0, y:0},{x:0, y:0},{x:1, y:1},{x:1, y:1},{x:2, y:2},{x:2, y:2}];
    io:println(uniq(data));
}
```

Prints the following expected results:

```
$ bal run uniq.bal 
Compiling source
        uniq.bal

Running executable

[1,2,3,4,5]
["foo","bar","zoo"]
[{"x":0,"y":0},{"x":1,"y":1},{"x":2,"y":2}]
```

Answer (score 3):

If the intended members of the set are not strings; we can use a table instead. Below is an example

```
import ballerina/io;

type TblConstraint record {|
    //can use a type that is a subtype of anydata
    readonly anydata keyValue;
|};

public function main() {
    int[] arr = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5];
    table<TblConstraint> key(keyValue) setImpl = table [];
    foreach int item in arr {
        if !setImpl.hasKey(item) {
            setImpl.put({keyValue:  item});
        }
    }
    
    //unique values as in a set
    io:println(setImpl.keys());
}
```