# Querying distinct values in Ballerina Query Expressions

Tags: ballerina, query-expressions

Is it possible to query `DISTINCT` values using Ballerina Query Expressions?

```
string[]|error connectorProducts = from record {string product;} {product} in products
        select product;
```

`connectorProducts` should only have `DISTINCT` values at the end.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved by incorporating a `group by` clause.

```
from record {string product;} {product} in products
      group by product
      select product;
```

Also see

- https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/aggregation
- https://ballerina.io/learn/work-with-data-using-queries-in-ballerina/#group-the-deaths-by-the-continent
- [How to create a set in Ballerina?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69503798/how-to-create-a-set-in-ballerina/77630375#77630375)

Note that there's an [open spec issue](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-spec/issues/776) to look into the possibility of adding an `array:unique` function as a straightforward alternative for when we just want to filter out unique members from an array.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to do this.
but you can use the `group by` clause and do this operation like this

```
import ballerina/io;

record {string product;}[] products = [{ product: "a"}, { product: "b"}, { product: "a"}, { product: "c"}, { product: "a"}];

function test() {
    string[]|error connectorProducts = from record {string product;} {product} in products
        group by product
        select product;
    
    io:println(connectorProducts);
}

public function main() {
    test();
}
```